# Batch/Bash scripting for Jailbroken iOS devices

Tags: ios, scripting, batch-file

So I have a jailbroken iPhone and would like to automate some tasks on my phone but I would rather do this myself, rather than download tweaks or apps that can achieve this same functionality.

I do not have a Mac computer, so developing apps and/or tweaks will be a pain in the butt, from what I have read, so then I got thinking about Batch files. And `.js` and `.vbs` files that you can use to automate things in Windows.

Does iOS have any similar or equivelant's to Batch file scripting? Can I write a script that can perform a simple task on my iPhone once I have launched that script file on my phone?

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, jailbroken phones have access to bash, and as such you can create bash script files.

[See here](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO.html) on how to start writing bash scripts. You write it to a file (typically ending in `.sh`), make it executable (via `chmod +x scriptFile.sh`), then run it (`./scriptFile.sh`). There is also access to Ruby and Python, so you could write scripts in those languages too if you prefer.

You also don't need to write the scripts on the device, you can write them on your PC, and transfer the files over via SCP. This gets a little more complex, as you'll need to install SSH (**and make sure you change the default passwords, there is a guide on how via Cydia**), and other tools in order to copy them over.

Comment: I see uses of terminal commands in that page, and a lot of references to Linux are being mentioned. Is there a download available to Windows that you know of? Or do you just use notepad, then transfer the file to iPhone, then use a Terminal app on the phone to make that file executable?

Comment: Ah ok. Yeah, I can already transfer files to my phone using Cyberduck (SSH client). These Bash scripts, once I make them executables, is there a way to make them appear on the Home screen with the other App icons?

Comment: Use notepad, or your favourite text editor (Notepad++), then transfer them over. Remember you'll be limited as to what you can do in a bash script, as the variety of commands that exist on Mac/Linux don't on iOS. Re the App Icons, thats a different question entirely; I'd suggest asking another question for that.